# Change of internal energy to kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, biophysics

Why do we feel tired while running as during running we are increasing our kinetic energy.
I understand that the energy inside us(from food or something else) is being converted to KE while running but when we stop to which form is this KE converted???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "run", i.e. contract your muscles, you use an amount of energy that was stored, in the form of chemical energy and such, in your body (see e.g. [this answer on quora](https://www.quora.com/How-is-energy-stored-in-muscles), or maybe look at biology.SE for more details on this regard).

That energy is converted into the kinetic energy that makes you move, which on its turn is dispersed into the environment due to a variety of factors. If this were not the case you could keep on moving at constant velocity without using more energy, which you know doesn't happen if you ever walked or run.

TL;DR: the kinetic energy is dispersed into the enrironment due to friction and a variety of other factors.